# flink Stream NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig.setRestartStrategy

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
>    org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig.setRestartStrategy(Lorg/apache/flink/api/common/restartstrategy/RestartStrategies$RestartStrategyConfiguration;)
>           at com.WriteIntoKafka.main(WriteIntoKafka.java:53)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:497)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:395)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.program.Client.runBlocking(Client.java:252)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.executeProgramBlocking(CliFrontend.java:676)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:326)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:978)
>           at org.apache.flink.client.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1028)

Comment: Im trying to run the the example of flink-streaming ,but it show this issue ,I also  run java -jar *** it is fine

Comment: Mind providing the code where the error occurs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in Flink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920543/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-in-flink)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodError` usually indicates incompatible versions. Please check that the versions of the Flink program and the running Flink instance are the same.

Comment: tks for ur help ,its really the incompatible versions like what u said.it working now